# placing google analytics script in each and every page in codeignatior

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-analytics

Hi i have a script of google analytics which i need to place in every and every page in the site,and site is developed in code ignatior,am confused how to place the script,can i place the the below sript in every page(view) of codeignatior,or should i place the script in some php file so that i can include the file in codeignatior view,please guide me as am new to codeignatior and google analytics
Will the google analytics script works if i place it in header or footer file of codeignatior..please guide me on this

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
some code

  ga('send', 'pageview');
//$trackingCode = file_get_contents('yourFile');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Core Class and extend it with CI_Controller
application/core/

```
class TEST_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  protected $footer_view;
  protected $footer_data;
  public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->footer_data = array();
    $this->footer_view = 'footer';

  }
  public function _output($output) {
  echo $this->load->view($this->footer_view, $this->footer_data, true);
 }
}//TEST_Controller.php
```

And Create view file which would automatically include to every request.

application/views/

```
<script>
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
some code

  ga('send', 'pageview');
//$trackingCode = file_get_contents('yourFile');
</script>
//footer.php
```

And Finally when you create your controller extend to this core class like

application/controllers

```
class Contact extends TEST_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
      echo "bla bla";
    }
}
```